# mongoose : insert data into an array of nested objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on a project using node.js mongodb. My schema somewhat looks like:

```
var Doctor = new Schema({
    email : String,
    password : String,
    Dname : String,
    blockAppoint:[{
        day:String,
        sslot:[Number],
        eslot:[Number],
        address:String,
        status1:String
    }]
});
```

If I take all these values as input from user, I can't figure out how to insert into the array of nested objects.
If my post api looks like:

```
var doc = new Doctor({
                email : req.body.email,
                password : req.body.password,
                name : req.body.Dname,
                blockAppoint:{
                              status1:req.body.xx,
                              day:req.body.day,
                              sslot:req.body.sslot,
                              eslot:req.body.eslot,
                              address:req.body.address
                            }
                });
doc.save(function(err){
                if(err){
                    res.send(err);
                    return;
                }
                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    message: 'doctor has been added!'   
                });
            });
```

I'm able to input just one entry into the database. Does anyone know how do I change my api code so as to be able to take read input into my database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the values to an array first using the **[`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** method:

```
var sslot = [], eslot = [], blockAppoint = [];
sslot.push(req.body.sslot);
eslot.push(req.body.eslot);
blockAppoint.push({
    status1: req.body.xx,
    day: req.body.day,
    sslot: sslot,
    eslot: eslot,
    address: req.body.address
});

var doc = new Doctor({
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    name: req.body.Dname,
    blockAppoint: blockAppoint
});
```

Comment: and what about the blockAppoint array?How do i take multiple inputs for the blockAppoint object?

Comment: @default Apologies, I hadn't seen that as an array. Let me edit the answer to correct method

Comment: I'm using postman to test my code and on giving an input through urlencoded form this still gives an error on giving multiple entries.